# Обновление datatable по интервалу

Tags: c#

Поток работает периодично каждые 3 секунды.  Допустим, программа работает на фоновом режиме. Если я хочу создать/обновить/удалить данные на sql server datatable обновляется?

```cs
 using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection())
        {
            cn.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=****;Initial Catalog=***;User ID=****;Password= ***";

            cn.Open();

            using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT s.id as shedule_id, s.name_ru as shedule_name_ru, s.sendType as shedule_sendType, c1.cod as typsendtype , s.typPeriod, c2.cod as time_name_ru, s.metaAlg, m.cod as meta_cod, s.dt_send, s.dt_beg as shedule_dt_beg, s.dt_send_daytime as shedule_dt_send_daytime, s.dt_period_end  as shedule_dt_period_end FROM Shedule s  inner join ClBaseItem c1 on s.sendType=c1.id inner join ClBaseItem c2 on s.typPeriod=c2.id inner join MetaAlg m on s.metaAlg=m.id", cn))

            using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
            {
                adapter.Fill(dt);
```

Что мне писать, чтобы datatable обновлялся?
Программа работает на фоновом режиме

```cs
public static void one(object state) {
    // тут надо писать  
}
```

Comment: datatable это что? Грид на форме? объект DataTable  с глобальной областью видимости?  У вас код не рабочий. Даже если добавить код получения обновлённых данных в one (более того, этот код у вас уже есть. И, я полагаю, так же есть код который выводит данные в datatable ) обновления происходить не будет.

Comment: @Alexey datatable это таблица с данными

Comment: Думаете стало понятнее?  То что datatable  это таблица данных ясно как день (название как бы намекает)  Вопрос был в том где она находится. Если вы хотите создать/обновить/удалить данные ГДЕ?  На сервере? Так у вас запрос входящих данных идёт из нескольких таблиц. Какую из них вы ходите обновлять? Что вы понимаете под "работает в фоновом режиме" и почему этот способ работы по вашему чем-то отличается от "работы в обычном режиме"?

Comment: таблица обновление `shedule`.

Comment: @Alexey Когда я обновляю таблицу на mssql , хочу чтобы и в `datatable` изменился. И периодично таймер проверял, что изменение было/не было на таблице

Comment: Где и как вы впервые записываете данные из бд в ваш datatable? Приведите код.

Comment: @Alexey я обновил вопрос

Comment: Попробуйте использовать [SqlDependency](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldependency(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov к сожалению, не понял как это делается(